# Conformal mapping vertical strip to upper half plane without exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis

Starting with the strip $\{\operatorname{Re}(z) < |a/2|, \operatorname{Im}(z) < 0$}

I first used $f(z) = iz$ to rotate it making it a horizontal strip $\{\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0, \operatorname{Im}(z) < |a/2|\}.$

Then I've used $g(z) = (z+ai/2)/(z-ai/2)\cdot(-ia/2)$ (sending $-ai/2$ to $0$, $0$ to $ai/2$, $ai/2$ to $\infty$) to map that horizontal strip to the first quadrant.

Fianlly using $h(z) = z^2$ to make it the upper half plane.

My question: Is this correct? All the other questions and answers on topic used exponentials/logarithms, but why wouldnt this work?

Comment: Sorry the absolute values should be around Re(z)/Im(z) not a/2

Comment: You only got rid of one 90° vertex (by the squaring). You still have another 90° vertex at infinitey and a cusp in the finite range

Comment: You're saying z^2 doesnt map the first quadrant to the whole upper plane? z = |z|exp(i*fi) doesnt it just square the radius and double the angle?

Comment: The Möbius transformation $g$ doesn't map the (half) strip to the quadrant. The image is a "triangle" with two 90° angles and one 0° angle.

Comment: And since there is one biholomorphism between the half-strip and the half-plane using the exponential function, and the automorphism group of the half-plane consists of rational functions, you cannot map a half-strip biholomorphically to a half-plane without using the exponential function. Unless you count using $\sin$ or $\cos$ as not using the exponential function.

Comment: Oh. Alright then thank you!

Comment: Thought isnt a triangle with two 90°angles and a 0°angles effectively the first quadrant? I guess your 2nd comment gives the answer, I don't know the mathematics of it as deeply though.

Comment: The quadrant has no 0° angle. If you view it as a triangle, it has two 90° angles and one 180° angle. (And a side of a triangle can be a circular arc, it need not be straight. To make a 0° angle, at least one of the sides meeting there must be a circular arc, unless the vertex is at $\infty$.)

Comment: Late as hell, but could you clarify how you found out the 3rd angle is 0°? I guess the angle between those 2 pararell lines $Im(z) = \pm a/2$ is 0°, but I thought conformal maps only conserved angles locally (Which I thought wouldnt be the case for those 2 lines, since they arent infinitesimaly close to each other). Pretty likely that I am getting something big wrong here